# Android : disable Text View links

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView containing a phone number, for example "01.40.56.55.20" (French number).

In this case, Android recognizes 1.40.56.55 as an IP address and links/underlines it.

How to remove this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following attribute to the `TextView` to render the digits as a phone number:

```
android:autoLink="phone"
```

Or just switch "phone" above to "none" to keep it plain.